# Problems about continuity in multivariable calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I just started studying multivariable calculus and I'm doing several exercises to practice but I'm really stuck on this problem:

Let

\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 \text{ if } y\leq 0 \text { or } y \geq x^2 \\
1 \text{ if } 0 < y < x^2
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

Show that $f(x,y) \rightarrow 0 $ along any line through the origin. Find a curve that Find a curve through the origin along which (except at the origin) f(x,y) has constant value 1. ¿Is $f(x,y)$ continuous at the origin?

Particularly I'm trying to solve this exercise considering $y=\lambda x$ with constant $\lambda$ but for now i am not able to get any result.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$f(x,\lambda x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }\lambda x\leqslant0\text{ or }\lambda x\geqslant x^2\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$So:

- If $\lambda=0$, $f(x,\lambda x)=0$ for every $x$.
- If $\lambda>0$, $f(x,\lambda x)=0$ when $x\leqslant\lambda$ and $f(x,\lambda x)=1$  otherwise.
- If $\lambda<0$, $f(x,\lambda x)=0$ when $x\geqslant\lambda$ and $f(x,\lambda x)=1$ otherwise.

In each case, $f(x,\lambda x)=0$ near $(0,0)$, and therefore $\lim_{x\to0}f(x,\lambda x)=0$.